# What does '^' sign mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I have searched through the documentation but cannot find the answer. Please help me answer this question. for example is this code

> $string = "Hello World" 
> echo strtolower($string) ^ strtoupper($string) ^ $string;

Comment: xor (exclusive or operator)

Comment: Albeit somewhat celverly, the third XOR in this case maps the byte discrepancies back into the alphanumeric character range.